# xsd validation is possible

Tags: javascript, xml, xsd

In our project

```
   UI(Name,age,emailid,etc...)-->convert data to xml--->DB
```

From our UI we pass data like name, age, emailid, street no like that via XML. Is it possible to validate name, emailid using DTD instead of JavaScript? If yes give one simple example it is very useful for me.

Comment: Please provide more information about your environment. Do you want the validation to happen on the client- or server-side? What do you mean with `DTD instead of JavaScript`? DTD is a scheme standard and javascript is a programming language...